# Firebase: Cannot start emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

**functions: Cannot start emulator. Error: Cannot find module '@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/config'**

This is the error message I get when I try to run functions locally on Mac. My Firebase version is 3.16.0. I tried doing `sudo npm install -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator` as well. But still no use. Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Working Solution!(OSX) None of the above worked for me. After a long struggle, I found the following solution.

```
cd my_project/functions

npm install @google-cloud/functions-emulator
```

Copy **@google-cloud/functions-emulator** folder generated inside *node_modules*.

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud && open .
```

Paste the **functions-emulator** folder here.

In your project's root directory, copy **package.json** inside *functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator*

```
cd /usr/local/lib && open .
```

Paste the **package.json** here.

```
npm install
```

Hurray! You are good to go. Now go back to your project's root directory and run.

```
sudo firebase serve --only hosting,functions
```

And the emulator should start normally.

Note: Do not run **sudo npm install -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator** since the files will be removed and reinstalled. This is where the installation fails and emulator fails to run.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 15):

Solution is:

```
yarn global add firebase-tools
yarn global add @google-cloud/functions-emulator --ignore-engines
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me.

1. npm uninstall -g firebase-tools && npm i -g firebase-tools
2. npm i --save @google-cloud/firestore
3. npm i --save @google-cloud/common-grpc
4. npm i -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator
5. npm i --save firebase-functions

current package.json snippet

```
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/common-grpc": "^0.5.3",
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^0.11.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1",
    "firebase-admin": "5.8.1" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, using Ubuntu 17.10.

**Note**: You do not need to, and should not, use sudo for the installation.

I resolved this by performing the following:

1. Uninstall any previously attempted installed of the functions emulator.

   ```
   npm uninstall -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator
   ```

   and to make sure:

   ```
   yarn global remove @google-cloud/functions-emulator
   ```
2. Delete all files in ~/.config/configstore/@google-cloud/functions-emulator. Note that there are some hidden files in this directory.

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.config/configstore/@google-cloud/functions-emulator
   ```
3. Install `nvm` (node version manager) by following the instructions here:

   > https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script
4. Use nvm to install a specific version of node - at the time of writing, the Google Cloud Function Emulator (version 1.0.0-alpha.29) specifically requires 6.11.5.

   ```
   nvm install 6.11.5
   ```
5. Install the Google Cloud Platform SDK:

   > https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
6. Reinstall the functions emulator:

   ```
   npm install -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator
   ```
7. Start the emulator to verify installation has succeeded:

   ```
   functions start
   ```

**IMPORTANT**: Subsequently, when attempting to create a function that can be tested locally or deployed to Google Cloud, you should use the `firebase init functions` command within your project, and allow this to install dependencies via npm. A walkthrough of creating a test function with Firebase can be found here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Answer (score 0):

My system: Ubuntu 16.04.3

I had the same problem and the reason is that "@google-cloud/functions-emulator" is not installed in the 'npm global packages folder'.

In my case it happened because I installed firebase-tools globally using yarn, and I used it because when installing firebase-tools globally using npm I was getting an folder access error, which did not happen with yarn.

What I did to solve the problem was to follow these simple instruction from npm website to use a different folder for npm global packages (https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).

Then I installed again with 'npm install -g firebase-tools' (**without sudo**) and it worked perfectly.